# Arrangement of 5 girls and 5 boys in a queue

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $n$ be the number of ways in which 5 boys and 5 girls can stand in a queue in such a way that all the girls stand consecutively in the queue. Let m be the number of ways in which 5 boys and 5 girls can stand in queue in such a way that exactly four girls stand consecutively in the queue. Then the value of $m/n$ is?

I found out $n = 6!5!$ By grouping all 5 girls together and then permutating. But I am unable to find number of ways to queue 4 girls together keeping the fifth girl segregated. Please provide a simple solution.

Comment: Is the answer for n = 5! x 5! x 6, m = 5! x 5! x 6 x 5, and so m/n= 5? If the answer is right i can elaborate more.

Comment: Yes 5 is the correct answer. Pls elaborate with expaination on how to find m

Comment: ok, i will post a quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to arrange 5 girls and 5 boys while keeping all 5 girls together is

$$n = (5!) (5!) (6)$$

[image]

For each of this configuration, there are 5 different ways to separate 1 girl while keeping the other  4 girls together. Hence,

$$m = (5!) (5!) (6) (5)$$

[image]

Therefore

$$\frac{m}{n} = \frac{(5!) (5!) (6) (5)}{(5!) (5!) (6)} = 5$$

Comment: Great thats a different approach from conventional methods . Thanks for answering

Comment: I got a query from your illustration in 2nd step . You are showing 5 ways to segregate a girl from the rest but if we consider selections then we multiply further by 5 as the segregated girl can be any one of the five . So shouldn't the answer be 25

Comment: @ArhamKothari do the girl switching before the names are assigned. then there are 5x more ways than previously, then only afterwards we select the 10 boy and girl names in 5! 5! ways

Comment: Ok got it now i had overcounted

Answer (score 3):

You have already found that the number of ways the boys and girls can be arranged with the girls all together is $6! 5!$.

Now apply the same method to the problem of $4$ girls standing together.  If we treat the $4$ girls as one object, then we have $1+1+5 = 7$ objects to arrange.  There are $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to select the group of $4$ girls, and they can be arranged in the group in $4!$ ways.  So all together there are $7! \binom{5}{4} 4!$ arrangements.  But this includes arrangements in which the $4$ girls stand next to the $1$ girl out, resulting in a group of $5$.  In fact each such arrangement has been counted twice, once with the single girl on the left and once with the single girl on the right. Since we don't want to include these, subtract twice the count from the first part, with result
$$7! \binom{5}{4} 4! - 2 \cdot 6!5!$$
as the number of ways to arrange the boys and girls with exactly $4$ girls standing together.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oops! Thank you, it's corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation for the number of arrangements in which all the girls are together is correct.

To calculate the number of arrangements in which exactly four of the girls are together, first arrange the five boys, which can be done in $5!$ ways.  Doing so creates six spaces in which the five girls can be placed, four between successive boys and two at the ends of the row.
$$\square b_1 \square b_2 \square b_3 \square b_4 \square b_5 \square$$
There are six ways to select the space in which four girls will be placed, five ways to select the space in which the remaining girl will be placed, and $5!$ ways to arrange the girls from left to right.  Hence,
$$m = 5! \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 5!$$